# How can I dynamically filter records by start and end dates in SQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql, google-bigquery

I have a table lets call it `users` that has user ids and corresponding start and end dates:

```
userId|start     |end
1200  |2019-01-01|2019-01-07
1900  |2017-06-01|2017-06-07
```

I have another table lets call it `purchases` that contains ALL user purchases:

```
userId|purchase_date|purchase_amt
  1200|   2019-01-03|       20.92
  1200|   2019-01-06|       40.95
  1900|   2017-06-03|      220.53
  1900|   2019-08-03|      893.02
  1500|   2019-08-03|      893.02
```

I'm looking for a way in SQL to return ONLY the `userId's` from the `users` table that are in `purchases` but also ONLY the purchases within the allotted time frame *(`start and end` dates in the `users` table)*

What I'm hoping to see in the query result is:

```
userId|purchase_date|purchase_amt
  1200|   2019-01-03|       20.92
  1200|   2019-01-06|       40.95
  1900|   2017-06-03|      220.53
```

All I have so far is for selecting all the purchases made by users only in the users table:

```
  SELECT
     p.*
  FROM
    `purchases` p
  WHERE
     p.userId IN ( SELECT u.userId FROM `users` u ) )
```

I still can't figure out the dynamic filtering of the purchases by start and end date.  Thanks!

Comment: what db you use - postgresql or google-bigquery?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do a `JOIN` instead of a `IN`:

```
SELECT p.*
FROM `purchases` p
JOIN `users` u
ON p.userId = u.userId
AND p.purchase_date BETWEEN u.start AND u.end
```

(assuming each user only shows up once in the users table)

Answer (score 1):

You can use an INNER JOIN KEYWORD to return ONLY the userIds' from the users table that are in purchases table.

Also, since your query requires purchase made within the allotted time frame, you can only use the purchase_date in the purchases table.

See Query below:

```
declare @start_date date = '2017-06-03'
declare @end_date date = '2019-01-03'

SELECT u.userid, p.purchase_date, p.purchase_amt FROM users u
INNER JOIN purchases p ON p.userid = u.userid
WHERE p.purchase_date BETWEEN @start_date AND @end_date
```

Answer (score 1):

A `join` is a perfectly reasonable way to do this.  However, you have started with filtering in the `where` clause and you can do so by using using `exists` instead of `in`:

```
select p.*
from purchases p
where exists (select 1
              from users u
              where u.userId = p.userId and
                    p.purchase_date >= u.start and
                    p.purchase_date <= u.end
             );
```